# Test if object is instanceof a parameter type

Tags: java, generics, instanceof

Is there a way to determine if an object is an instance of a generic type?

```
public <T> test(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof T) {
        ...
    }
}
```

That clearly doesn't work. Is there an alternative? Like I want to use Java reflection to instantiate a class and then check to make sure it is of type generic `T`.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

The only way you can do this check is if you have the `Class` object representing the type:

```
Class<T> type; //maybe passed into the method
if ( type.isInstance(obj) ) {
   //...
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to get `type` as a method parameter, maybe you want to initialize it: `Class type = ((T) new Object()).getClass();`

Comment: @JordiVilaplana That is not right, it will give you java.lang.Object as the class. Check this out: http://ideone.com/bxt9Jq

Comment: Use: `Class<T> type = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];`

Answer (score 27):

To extend the sample of Mark Peters, often you want to do something like:

```
Class<T> type; //maybe passed to the method
if ( type.isInstance(obj) ) {
   T t = type.cast(obj);
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 15):

If you don't want to pass Class type as a parameter as mentioned by Mark Peters, you can use the following code. Kudos to David O'Meara.

```
  Class<T> type = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass())
                  .getActualTypeArguments()[0];
  if (type.isInstance(obj)) {
      ...
  }
```

Comment: It gives `Type safety: Unchecked cast from Type to Class<T>`

Answer (score 5):

You could try this,

```
// Cast your object to the generic type.
T data = null;
try {
    data = (T) obj;
} catch (ClassCastException cce) {
    // Log the error.
}

// Check if the cast completed successfully.
if(data != null) {
    // whatever....
}
```

Comment: **This does not work!** The cast succeeds for **all** types. Which is why it gives an "Unchecked cast" compile warning.

Answer (score 3):

It would make more sense to put the restriction on where the type `T` is used to parametrise the `Class` type. When you pass the type in, instead of using something like `Class<?>`, you should use `Class<? extends T>`.

Comment: If you want to know the exact type of T at runtime, it is important to require that the caller pass in a Class<T>, not a Class<? extends T>. For example, Puce's code would not compile with Class<? extends T>.

Answer (score 1):

This will only work (partly) if you have an object of type T. Then you can get the class of that object, see `java.lang.Class<T>` and find if it's the same as the object in question.

But note that this goes counter the very reason we have genrics: using a generic type is a way to say that you don't care what type it really is (up to upper and lower bounds that may be specified).

Comment: The Class<?> returned from a .getClass() call on a non-null T instance is not guaranteed to be a Class<T>. The best you can guarantee is that it's a Class<? extends T>.