# equals method in java generic class

Tags: java, equals

I hava a generic class called ArrayBag. I want to override equals method. So i wrote

```
public boolean equals(T other){

} // gives error
```

> > error message: Name clash: The method equals(T) of type ArrayBag has the same erasure as equals(Object) of type Object but does not 
> >      override it

Comment: It's good practice to use the `@Override` annotation too.

Comment: You should always be writing "equals(Object)", even if you are not using generics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The equals method you are trying to override expects an `Object`. When your code is translated to byte code, type erasure transforms your `T` into an `Object`, which conflicts with the existing equals method.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (other instanceof T)
    {
        T o = (T) other;
        ...
    }
}
```

Inside the method you can handle casting to `T`.

Comment: that helps a lot mate.. Also could you please explain what instanceOf does??

Comment: `instanceof` will check to see if the `other` object is of type `T`. This prevents a possible exception when casting the object. If it is not of type `T`, the `equals` method should return false.

Comment: There is the error in the generic class when using the instanceof . The links describe the detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734720/java-generics-obj-instanceof-t  . In short, the keyword "instanceof " is not allowed to use in the java generic class.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `equals(T other)` with `equals(Object other)`, and then cast `other` to `T` inside the  method implementation.

```
public boolean equals(Object other)
{
    T t = (T) other;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Be careful of casting without checking to see if the object is as instance of T first. You may end up with a ClassCastException.

Answer (score 0):

you need this.

```
public boolean equals(Object other){
      T t = (T) other;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any time you need to override a method, the signature must be the same as the method to be overriden. Therefore you must pass Object as the one and only argument to your equals method for it to function as desired.

As an alternative to Grantham's solid solution, you can use getClass() in place of instanceof, if for example you plan on extending your generic class and don't want sub class instances to ever equal your super class instances.

That would look like:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (other != null && getClass() == other.getClass()) {
        T o = (T) other;

        // ...

    }
    return false;
}
```