# method that return an arraylist of generic type according to how it is called

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, foreach

In order to reduce code duplication I replace this code

```
    ArrayList<Vertex> allVertice = new ArrayList<>(hypergraph.getVertices());

    System.out.println(allVertice.size());
    //hypergraph.getVerticebyType();
    ArrayList<ImageVertex> allImVetice = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<TagVertex> allTagVetice =  new ArrayList<>();

    ArrayList<LocationVertex> allLocVetice = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Vertex vertex : allVertice) {
        if (vertex instanceof ImageVertex)

            allImVetice.add((ImageVertex)vertex);

        else if (vertex instanceof TagVertex)

            allTagVetice.add((TagVertex)vertex);

        else if (vertex instanceof LocationVertex)

            allLocVetice.add((LocationVertex)vertex);
    }
```

by this method

```
  public <T extends Vertex<?> > ArrayList<T> getVerticebyType( ) {

        ArrayList<T> array = new ArrayList<T>();

        for (Vertex<?> vertex : this.getAllVertice()) {
            if (vertex instanceof Vertex<?>)
                array.add((T) vertex);

    }
        return array;

}
```

but when I test this instruction

`ArrayList<ImageVertex>=hyperGraph.getVerticebyType();`

it return all vertex regardless their type!

what is the problem and how to fix it ?

Comment: This is just a guess, because I'm not familiar with java generics, But i'd expect something of the `if (vertex instanceof T)` flavor

Answer (score 1):

The literal equivalent would be to pass a `Class<T>` in (assuming `T` is not itself a generic type) and use `Class.cast` (probably with `Class.isInstance`). However using `instanceof` is an indication you are doing something wrong; reflection, orders of magnitude more so.

Answer (score 0):

change this line:
`vertex instanceof Vertex<?>` (that tests if vertex is a vertex) to this:
`vertex instanceof T` (this one checks if vertex is of type T)

also make sure you're familiar with Oracle tutorial and generics restrictions: [Oracle Generics Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#cannotCast)

Comment: I tried it before 

I get this error `Cannot perform instanceof check against type parameter T. Use its erasure Vertex<?> instead since further generic type information will be erased at runtime`

Comment: then try the following (from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734720/java-generics-obj-instanceof-t):
`Class<T> type;
if ( type.isInstance(obj) ) {
   //...
}`

Comment: It mean that I should create a generic class Class<T> for each type ! 
it is unusual