# Can I check for variable is Type T?

Tags: generics, kotlin, type-erasure, type-systems

I plan to set my coordinator if only it is type T sent.

```
interface ViewSurface<T : Coordinator> {
    var coordinator: T

    fun setCoor(coordinator: Coordinator) {
        if (coordinator is T) {
            this.coordinator = coordinator
        }
    }
}
```

The above code complaint `Cannot check for erased type: T`. How could I change to get the right syntax yet achieve what I wanted?

Comment: Probably the same way as with 'standard Java', which is round-about due to .. Type Erasure. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/339699/2864740 for how/why this occurs. But why not only accept `coordinator: T`?

Answer (score 4):

Because at runtime, the generic type parameters are all gone (erased), the runtime can't really check whether `coordinator is T` because it has no idea what `T` is.

Instead of checking the type of `coordinator` before assigning it, why not change the parameter type from `Coordinator` to `T` so that the *compiler* can guarantee that `coordinator` will always be assignable to the `coordinator` property in the interface?

```
fun setCoor(coordinator: T) {
    this.coordinator = coordinator
}
```

As you can see, the `setCoor` method isn't really needed. You can just set the property normally:

```
coordinator = ...
```

Comment: While this [probably] works in this case, and such a type-sound approach with generics is an improvement overall, it doesn't answer the fundamental question :} At some times one *really does* want to have access to 'the type of T' (even if such itself feeds into an "unsafe" cast). Reified generics makes this trivial, and Java/Kotlin (without such) need to adopt slightly different approaches..

Comment: @user2864740 I think there are many answers out there that already address this in Java. Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437897/how-to-get-a-class-instance-of-generics-type-t) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734720/test-if-object-is-instanceof-a-parameter-type). If you think a kotlin version is needed. You can post question and answer it yourself. :)

Comment: I do think a Kotlin version would be handy. And that *is* what the OP asked for, even if an XY question. Y might be correct, but X was still asked.