# Java : how to use the Param to present a class

Tags: java

I have a question about param,  what param to present the class, such as if I findBuildingsType( buildingEntities, Village) it will return all village building  as a result

[image]

Comment: Hello, Zhenwei, welcome to the site. It's not clear what you are asking. Please include the code as text and not as an image. Check [ask]

Comment: don't look for instanceof, use currBuildings.getClass().getName() or similar, or pass [Type].class instead of the name of the class and compare classes

Comment: @RubioRic it's quite clear what is going wrong: if ( myInteger instanceof "Integer") is not the same as if ( myInteger instanceof Integer )

Comment: @Stultuske Ah, I didn't see that type was an argument of the method and a String.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Test if object is instanceof a parameter type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734720/test-if-object-is-instanceof-a-parameter-type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome.

You can deliver a Class via arguments like this:

```
private List<Building> findBuildingsType(List<Building> buildings, Class<? extends Building> typ) {
    List<Building> re = new ArrayList<>();
    
    for (Building building : buildings) {
        if (typ.isInstance(building)) {
            re.add(building);
        }
    }
    
    return re;
}
```

Especially for your problem consider using [streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html):

```
List<Building> buildingsOfTypeMansion = buildings.stream().filter(building -> building instanceof Mansion).collect(Collectors.toList());
```